# Server certificate change issue for Huawei PushKit Uplink message

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-push-notification

Currently, if you want to apply "Uplink message sending" for your apps in **Huawei PushKit**, you must provide a Url and it's Https certificate

If the certificate gets expired or changed, an update is needed for the uplink to keep working.

However, the issue gets serious when the number of apps becomes relatively large. This would make the update process difficult.

Is there anyway to apply the uplink message without worrying about the certificate change over time?

Is there a reason that Huawei does not try to get the certificate  of the passed Url itself and check it periodically and update it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to apply the uplink message without worrying about the
> certificate change over time?

How many apps do you have and and how frequently do you change your server certificate? According to the instruction [here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-upstream-message-sending-0000001050040118-V5#EN-US_TOPIC_0000001124013093__p8243174012291), it is just a matter of changing the URL and upload the PEM file. Per Shirley's suggestion, the developer server monitors the certificate validity period and will remind you to update the certificate before it expires.

1. Sign in to [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html#/).
2. Select **My projects**, find your project from the project list, and
   click the app for which you need to send messages. Go to **Grow** > **Push
   Kit** > **Settings**. Find **Receive uplink message** and click **Enable**.
3. Set Destination URL and HTTPS certificate (in PEM format).

> Is there a reason that Huawei does not try to get the certificate of
> the passed Url itself and check it periodically and update it?

Huawei AppGallery Connect treats security and communication seriously so it is important to make sure that the developer follow the security best practice to update their own HTTPS URL & certificate.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to apply the uplink message without worrying about the certificate change over time?

If the uplink message fails to be sent, the device will receive an error code.  After receiving the error code, the device instructs the device to update the certificate.Alternatively, the developer server monitors the certificate validity period and reminds you to update the certificate before it expires.

> Is there a reason that Huawei does not try to get the certificate of the passed Url itself and check it periodically and update it?

To meet security compliance requirements, Huawei must check the validity of certificates.